# How to land the player right in the middle of the next stair

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 3D game like "Stairs By Ketchapp" in Unity.
I am moving the stairs backward instead of moving the player forward by using "transform.Translate" and I am making the player(which is a ball) jump whenever it hit the ground.
The player can only move on the X-axis, Y-axis and I have frozen the Z coordinates for the player so that it cannot move forward or backward by hitting the edge of a stair. Whenever the player hits the ground it jumps back.
The problem is with the landing of the player.
I want the player to land right in the middle of the next stair regardless of its position on the X-axis. so that it can look like it traveled the distance of one stair in one jump.

Here is the stair script

```
public class Stairmovement : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed;

Vector3 destroyPos;
private void Start()
{
    destroyPos = new Vector3(0, -0.5f, -2f);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, -0.5f, -2f) * Time.deltaTime * speed);


    if(transform.position.z <= destroyPos.z)
    {
        //transform.position = new Vector3(0, 4f, 16);
        transform.position = new Vector3(0, transform.position.y + 4.5f, transform.position.z + 18f);
    }
}
```

}

And this is my player script

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody myRigidbody;

public bool grounded;

public float jumpSpeed;
public float forwardSpeed;
public float fallMultiplier;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (grounded)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpSpeed, forwardSpeed);
        grounded = false;
    }
    if (this.gameObject.transform.position.y > 1f)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity += Vector3.up * Physics.gravity.y * (fallMultiplier) * Time.deltaTime;
    }



}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "Ground")
    {
        Debug.Log("Grounded");
        grounded = true;
    }
}
```

}

I need your help guys, I hope you guys can understand the problem, if not then please do let me know. I'll try to explain it better. I'll appreciate any kind of help, Thank you.

This is an image showing the difference between jumping position and landing position. [Note: please keep it in mind that I am moving the stairs.]
  ![Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW9FK.png

Answer (score 0):

The idea is you need to play with the stair's backward movement speed so that each stair will only move "1 stair length" through the duration of time that ball is on air. So lets say if each stair's movement taking 1 second, then the ball should also be on air exaclty 1 second and land on the stair.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already tried it, when I give the stairs the speed value of 0.9575 it gives the desired result but I want to increase the game speed, for example when the player reaches a 100 score the movement speed increases which will bring it back to the landing problem. Is there a way to decrease the air time of the player?

Comment: Yes you can reduce the jumpspeed or increase fallmultiplier or both.